# Changing value in data frame not possible

Tags: r

I created a data frame:

```
df <- mydata %>%
  mutate(length.class=cut(mydata$count,breaks = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000),include.lowest=TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(length.class) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

This results `df$length.class` to have values like "(100,1e+03]" while I prefer to have "(100,1000]". However, changing it manually doesn't work:

```
df$length.class[df$length.class == "(100,1e+03]"] <- "(100,1000]"

Warnmeldung:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$length.class == "(100,1e+03]", value = c(1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Why is changing the string not possible and what tries R to tell me with this message?

Bonus question: how can I get the original value back or address the changed row (4)? After executing the change command there's now a "NA" instead of "(100,1e+03]".

Comment: I believe you want to change the labels of the factor, not the values. You may be able to set the labels when you cut. See `?cut`

Comment: (Side note: I find it interesting that the labels created by `cut` do not honor `options(scipen = 5)`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dig.lab` argument in `cut` should take care of this.

From the documentation:

> integer which is used when labels are not given. It determines the
>   number of digits used in formatting the break numbers.

In your case, you want to show 5 digits so your code would be

```
mydata %>%
    mutate(length.class = cut(count, breaks = c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), 
                            include.lowest = TRUE, dig.lab = 5))
```

The levels of the resulting factor look like:

```
[1] "[1,10]"       "(10,100]"     "(100,1000]"   "(1000,10000]"
```

Comment: ahhhh, I knew I would learn something new today, thanks @aosmith!

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks @aosmith and all others!

Answer (score 1):

The warning (below) tells you all you need to know.

```
Warnmeldung:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$length.class == "(100,1e+03]", value = c(1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

`df$length.class` is a `factor`, whose values are stored as distinct `levels`. You're trying to replace the values in the incorrect manner. The appropriate way is to change the `levels`, not the displayed values. Factors are stored as integers, with a map between the integers in memory and the `levels` used for display.

The first option is compact, though it's admittedly not very readable. Or you could always use two lines of code

```
levels(df$length.class)[ which(levels(df$length.class) == "(100,1e+03]") ] <- "(100,1000]"

lvl_idx <- which(levels(df$length.class) == "(100,1e+03]") 
levels(df$length.class)[lvl_idx] <- "(100,1000]"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
brks <- 10^(0:4)
# ensure one in each bin
mydata <- data.frame(count = brks[-1] - diff(brks)/2)

# create labels to be used in `cut`
lbls <- mapply(paste0, "(", head(brks, n = -1), ",", brks[-1], "]")
# fix the first, it's open on the left
lbls[1] <- paste0("[", brks[1], ",", brks[2], "]")

df <- mydata %>%
  mutate(length.class = cut(count, breaks = brks, labels = lbls,
         include.lowest = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(length.class) %>% summarise(count = n())
df
# # A tibble: 4 x 2
#   length.class count
#         <fctr> <int>
# 1       [1,10]     1
# 2     (10,100]     1
# 3   (100,1000]     1
# 4 (1000,10000]     1
```

If you don't want to redo the calculation, you can simply do:

```
labels(df$length.count) <- lbls
```

(assuming you defined `lbls` correctly per the number of levels/bins).

Some notes about the code:

- you don't need `mydata$` within `mutate`: your code references the value of `mydata$count` outside of the pipe, which can be different from the current value of the `count` column of the data.frame in the pipe; it isn't here, but it easily can be, especially with preceding `mutate` or `group_by` verbs.
- minor, but many consider the use of dots in variable names to be more than just a style issue: because of the way R does class inheritance, it can cause some unnecessary lookups (though I think that's more with dotted function names than variables, it's also about consistency in a naming convention).